# Power BI Percentage of Total Using Field Parameters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI Dataset of which I'm using Field Parameters to filter data in a Matrix Visual, which works perfectly.

I created a separate Field Parameter whereby I can switch between different measures as well.

Measures included are

- CountRows
- Total Sales
- Percentage of Total Sales

The first 2 measures works perfectly, however the percentage of total sales, does not, becuase I'm calculating the Percentage of Total Sales, using the following DAX:

```
% Total =
VAR tot =
    CALCULATE ( [AccountID Count], ALLSELECTED ( DimProduct ) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( [AccountID Count], tot )
```

The result is 100% for everything else, unless I change my Dimension Field Parameter to Product, which is what I actually want.

I need my Percentage of Total measure to calculate based on any Dimension Field Parameter I select.

How do I achieve this?

I even tried changing the DAX to:

```
% Total =
VAR tot =
    CALCULATE ( [AccountID Count], ALLSELECTED ( DimensionFilter ) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( [AccountID Count], tot )
```

Which also just returned 100% for everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the following:

**DAX:**

```
% Total = 
VAR al =
    CALCULATE (
        [AccountID Count],
        ALLSELECTED ( DimDate ),
        ALLSELECTED ( DimBranch ),
        ALLSELECTED ( DimCountry ),
        ALLSELECTED ( DimCustomerService ),
        ALLSELECTED ( DimProduct )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( [AccountID Count], al )
```

This works perfectly.